# Is it possible to get emesene to work with MeMenu?

Tags: indicator, memenu, emesene

Is it Possible to? or is it an emesene problem?, is there a plug in or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no way for an external app to integrate with the MeMenu(if you mean the "place" where you can change your status). So it's not completely an emesene's fault.
By the way there could be a solution and i'll force the emesene's guys to fix that.

Comment: so, only empathy can make use of the MeMenu? :( , if you could do that i'll thank you so much.

Comment: yes..only empathy can use the MeMenu and there are no plans to change that...I can't guarantee that i'll fix that but as soon as possible i'll give a look to the code and i'll see what i can do...:)

Comment: Great news so far! I've fixed it! The MeMenu in Natty will support Emesene2!!!  https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-me/+bug/741163

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is it you are looking for but [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/how-to-add-more-apps-to-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu/) is a workaround.

Edit: this [ppa's](https://launchpad.net/~bjfs/+archive/ppa) emesene is also said to be integrated with messaging menu.

Comment: nice post sagarchalise

Comment: not really, the workaround it's for the Messanging Menu (which integrates gwibber and evolution mail by default) i added emsene there but it acts like a launcher, the MeMenu it's the indicator that shows your name or your username ,that's next to it where you can set your status (online, busy, offline, etc)