# Integrate emesene with the messaging menu

Tags: messaging-menu, emesene

Is there anyway of integrating emesene with the messaging menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using emesene 1.6.* there is a plugin ( http://forum.emesene.org/index.php/topic,2501.0.html ). Instead if you are using emesene 2.0 (beta) it's already integrated by default.
Also the MeMenu integration is behind the corner..:)

Comment: the 1.6 plugin can cause a major bug with receiving messages (That is why I did not link to it)

Answer (score 1):

I kinda answered to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25585/is-it-possible-to-get-emesene-to-work-with-memenu/25595#25595) but [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/how-to-add-more-apps-to-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu/) is a workaround.

this [ppa's](https://launchpad.net/~bjfs/+archive/ppa) emesene is also said to be integrated with messaging menu.